# Javascript key down only firing once when key is held down

Tags: javascript

I'm using the following code to load a certain page whenever the w,s,a,d keys are pressed.

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
e = e || window.event;
key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
var keys = { 
  87: '{$up}', 
  68: '{$right}', 
  83: '{$down}', 
  65: '{$left}'
};
if (keys[key]) window.location.href = keys[key];
});
</script>
```

The php variables just contain the url address.

My question is, is it possible to have the keypress only register once per click?
At the moment if you hold the key down it fires rapidly.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: You could always use keyup instead.  Fires once per "click".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with the 'keyup' event:

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
e = e || window.event;
key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
var keys = { 
  87: '{$up}', 
  68: '{$right}', 
  83: '{$down}', 
  65: '{$left}'
};
if (keys[key]) window.location.href = keys[key];
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise it was this simple :P

Answer (score 0):

You can store a list of the pressed keys, and at `keydown` only run your code if the key wasn't in the list. At `keyup` remove the entry from the list.

```js
var keysDown = {};
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  varkey = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if(keysDown[key]) return;
  keysDown[key] = true;
  // Do something
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  delete keysDown[key];
});
```

```js
var keysDown = {};
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  if(keysDown[key]) return;
  keysDown[key] = true;
  var keys = { 
    87: '{$up}', 
    68: '{$right}', 
    83: '{$down}', 
    65: '{$left}'
  };
  console.log(keys[key]);
});
document.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  e = e || window.event;
  var key = e.keyCode || e.charCode;
  delete keysDown[key];
});
```